# Slide-up view in Flutter

Tags: mobile, view, dart, flutter, slideup

I'm trying to make something similar to google/apple maps screen in flutter. I just started experimenting in Flutter and I have a hard time understand that "Draggable widget". Could someone give me example code how they made their slide-up view, I can learn from? I can't find any.

Comment: I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjAQglJKcb4 video that uses https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html and you don't need plugins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Draggable`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) (and [`DragTarget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html)) is not used for what you call `slide-up view`

`slide-up view`, from the android world, is for bottom aligned modals.
`Draggable` is to transfer data using Drag&Drop.

In flutter, bottom modals are fairly simple :

First, make sure you have somewhere above in your tree a `Scaffold`. As it's what will position everything together.

Then, call either `showBottomSheet` or `showModalBottomSheet` with whatever content you like. The content will now automatically appear at the bottom of your screen.

That's it, your job is done ! You can optionally now add a custom close event. For this, you'll just have to call `Navigator.pop(context)`.
But both modal and non-modal bottom sheet can be closed out of the box using common gestures. Such as back button, navbar back, of click outside.

Full example :

```
class MyExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Example')),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Builder(builder: (context) {
            return new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => modal(context),
                  child: new Text("modal"),
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => showSlideupView(context),
                  child: new Text("non modal"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showSlideupView(BuildContext context) {
    showBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return new Container(
            child: new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: new Text("Click me to close this non-modal bottom sheet"),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  modal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Text("This is a modal bottom sheet !"),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your example is great! Now what if I want expand the bottom view such as google maps when you click marker on a map and bottom view pops up, then you can expand it by sliding it up. That's why the "draggable" confused me. Do I need to make draggable for that ?

Comment: No draggable is not used for drag actions. You can instead use `GestureDetector` and `onVerticalDrag`.

Answer (score 13):

There's also the [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sliding_up_panel) Flutter library you could use to implement the same sort of design that Google/Apple Maps uses.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the collapsed widget and show it upon some event?

Comment: It is possible now yes.  It has various properties you can manipulate using setState()

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use [Sliding Up Panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) plugin to do that, its awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative: From the docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```